# Unit testing request timeout in a task queue task

Tags: java, google-app-engine, unit-testing, task-queue

According to the [available documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/LocalServiceTestHelper#setRemainingMillisTimer) the app engine test helper class `LocalServiceTestHelper` can simulate the result from `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis()`.

This all works fine as long as the code runs in the same thread as the helper is created but is seems that when the the test is multithreaded (such as when testing a Deferred task) the second thread will not use the simulated response.

**How do a get the helper class to set the return value of `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis()` in a task queue task?**

Answer (score 1):

Calling `LocalServiceTestHelper.setUp()` will only set your environment in the current thread, as you found.

After calling `setUp()`, you should be able to get the just-set environment using `ApiProxy.Environment testEnv = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()`;wrap `testEnv` in an implementation of `ApiProxy.EnvironmentFactory` which always returns `testEnv`. Then, call `ApiProxy.setEnvironmentFactory`, passing in that new factory.

```
final ApiProxy.Environment testEnv = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment();
ApiProxy.setEnvironmentFactory(new ApiProxy.EnvironmentFactory() {
  @Override
  public ApiProxy.Environment newEnvironment() { return testEnv; }
};
```

This should result in the same environment being used in all threads.

This approach is untested, but looks reasonable according to the doc.

Comment: Seems like a possible solution (according to the docs) but when trying to actually implement it I can not find the interface `ApiProxy.EnvironmentFactory` in the SDK. I'm working with app engine 1.9.6 by the way.